# Python Queue type in groovy

Tags: python, multithreading, groovy, queue

I am looking for something similar as Queue type in Python in Groovy language.

In python Queues let to exchange information between threads and take care about all locking problems/challenges. So one thread can simply add a task to queue

```
while True:
    if self.task_ready():
        task = self.get_task()
        self.queue.put(task) 
        print 'Task %s added to queue' % (task.name)
```

and worker threads can:

```
while True:
    self.queue.get()  # this is read blocking action
    self.proces_task(task)
```

is there a way to do it in such easy way in Groovy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Queue.

Java has [LinkedBlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) in its java.util.concurrent package which you can just use from Groovy.  There's an article [over here on JavaLobby](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t16278.html) that discusses these structures (obviously from a Java perspective, but you can use the all from Groovy)